# Append lines to beginning of all files in a directory

Tags: cat

I am trying to prepend two lines to the beginning of all the files in a directory.

I can do it for an individual file using the following command:

```
echo -e "% First Line\n% "$(date)"\n\n$(cat file1.txt)">file1.txt
```

How can I prepend two lines to the beginning of *all* files in a directory?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  "Append" means to add on to existing content, at the end.  "Prepend" means to insert before existing content, at the beginning.  "Overwrite" means to remove all existing content and replace with the new content.  You are asking about all three things as though they are the same.  Please edit your question.

Comment: [tag:cat] is entirely the wrong tool for this. Maybe re-tag with something like [tag:text-processing] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your platform supports in-place editing with `sed`, try something like

```
sed -i "1i\\
First line\\
$(date)" *
```

Unfortunately, this part of `sed` is somewhat unwieldy; I remember having a hard time figuring out the precise syntax from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

First, your command:

```
echo -e "% First Line\n% "$(date)"\n\n$(cat file1.txt)">file1.txt
```

This is **highly not recommended.**  If your file contains any backslashes at all you will be in trouble.  Please read up on quoting and command substitution.

---

For a single file, the recommended POSIX way to insert lines at the beginning of the file is:

```
printf '%s\n' 0a 'First line' '2nd line; 3rd line is empty' '' . x | ex file.txt
```

`0a` means "append after line 0."  It's a command to `ex`, the POSIX file editor (and another form of the `vi` editor, incidentally).  The `.` on a line by itself ends the appending.  `x` saves and exits.

To do multiple files all at once, use a `for` loop and a file glob:

```
for f in *.txt; do
  printf '%s\n' 0a '# This line heads all files' . x | ex "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i -lpe '
   $FNR++ or print "% First Line\n%", `date`, $\;
   $FNR = 0 if eof;
' *.txt
```

---

Only for the first line of input for every file we print the desired strings. We put in the `ORS` `$\` in the `print` to put the extra newline as the OP requires based on the `echo` statement.